# working with doctrine and zend framework 2

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework2

i worked with doctrine and zend framework 1 before and installed doctrine as follows:

- put doctrine library in library folder under website root.
- add below function in bootstrap.php file 
  protected function _initDoctrine()
  {
      require_once 'Doctrine/Doctrine.php';
      $this->getApplication()
      ->getAutoloader()
      ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine','autoload'),'Doctrine');

  ```
  $manager=Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
  $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING, Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE);

  $config=$this->getOption('Doctrine');
  $conn=Doctrine_Manager::connection($config['dsn'],'doctrine');
  return $conn;
  ```

  }
- add this line in to application.ini (doctrine.dsn = "mysql://root@localhost/mydb")
- Auto generate models from DB using doctrine script.

then i create an object from my generated models and use it to add,update or delete records in database but when i tried to use zend framework 2 i failed to install and use doctrine with it and when google it i found something called entity and some other points i didn't know so please i want to know how to install doctrine with zend 2 with same idea like i installed before and use it with my zend framework 2 projects. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Doctrine2 with ZF2, you can include [DoctrineModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule) and [DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule) for the ORM part in your `composer.json`.

They are very usefull and very well documented